# Displaying user input in table form

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am using flash cs5 with Action script3. The user enters the number of rows and columns into two textinput components and clicks submit button. Then a empty table like structure should be displayed with the user specified number of rows and columns. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Google "Grid Layout with Action Script". You basically will need to create the Grid Layout object and then add child.

There are quite a few references out there.